# What are some computational tools for isnad or matn analysis of hadith?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

Analyzing the chain (isnad) of hadith is essential for authentication.  Comparison of the content (matn) of the hadiths can also be very helpful. I am looking for any computational tools that may exist for tracking chains of narrations or keeping up with all the different narrators, discontinuities, etc for different hadiths. Additionally, having a tool that could easily compare hadith contents would be helpful. I guess I could make my own for content analysis, I think, based on sunnah.con's API (IIRC).

Anything and everything that could be helpful would be appreciated! Even a family tree of narrators would be nice.

Comment: Islamweb library used to have some relevant functionality: cross-references and grading of each chain. You can also find some databases of hadith transmitters on google, e.g. [this](http://muslimscholars.info/).

Comment: Great thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further investigation (with input from the comment above), here are my preliminary results.

**Resources**:

- [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/articles/70/the-noble-hadeeth)
- [Muslim Scholars Database](http://muslimscholars.info/)

**[People](https://ihsn.hcommons.org/members/) currently working on computational hadith analysis**:

- Irene Kirchner, PhD student at Georgetown University
- Mairaj Syed, professor at UC Davis
- Others not listed that are included from the papers below

**Relevant Academic Papers**:

- "[A Quantitative Analysis of Schacht's Hadith Backgrowth Theory](https://religions.ucdavis.edu/sites/religions.ucdavis.edu/files/news/files/donald_pinckney_and_alexander_ditzel_rst_writing_prize.pdf)"
- “[Isnad Al-Hadith Computational Authentication: An Analysis Hierarchically](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7814928)"
- Comparative Study of Machine Learning Approach on Malay Translated Hadith Text Classification based on Sanad
- "[Muhadith: A Cloud Based Distributed Expert System for Classification of Ahadith](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~bilal/B_M_2012_FIT.pdf)"
- "[Computational and natural language processing based studies of hadith literature: a survey](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331848759_Computational_and_natural_language_processing_based_studies_of_hadith_literature_a_survey)"
- "[A Rich Arabic WordNet Resource for Al-Hadith Al-Shareef](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050917321555)"
- “A Review and Analysis for A Hierarchy from Computational Hadith to Isnad Authenticity Examination”
- "[Al-Hadith Text Classifier](https://scialert.net/fulltextmobile/?doi=jas.2005.584.587) ([pdf](http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/jas/2005/584-587.pdf))